# Get digits from string

Tags: python, string, digit

I want to parse through a line and fetch a specific set of digits from it with python.

the string looks like this:
"72732672 bytes available (56004608 bytes used)"
the digits could be any numerical value, which makes me unable to pre-define this.
The specific target is in this case is "72732672".

Any of you have a solution to this?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Do you just need to check if the target is in the string?

Answer (score 5):

So you want the integers from the string? One way is to use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). But this can be done without using regular expressions.

```
>>> line = "72732672 bytes available (56004608 bytes used)" 
>>> [int(word) for word in line.split() if word.isdigit()]
[72732672]
```

IF you want to use regular expressions -

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', line)
['72732672', '56004608']
```

Comment: Thanks. This one helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `re` module:

```
>>> digits = re.compile(r'[0-9]+')
>>> digits.findall("72732672 bytes available (56004608 bytes used)")
['72732672', '56004608']
```

You can convert to actual numbers with int:

```
>>> l = digits.findall("72732672 bytes available (56004608 bytes used)")
>>> l = [int(x) for x in l]
>>> l
[72732672, 56004608]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "72732672 bytes available (56004608 bytes used)"
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', text)
['72732672', '56004608']
```